# Android Studio 2020.3.1 cannot login to github

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to checkout a project from Github using Android Studio.

I select "Get from VCS", then enter github URL.

I then get asked if I want to "Log In via GitHub". I select this option and select "Autorize with GitHub".

Then I get to this screen:

[image]

I've tried to enter my github email+password, my github username+password, my jetbrains email+password but none are accepted. Anyone else know what username and password this 127.0.0.1:63342 wants?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened to me also with android studio.

So i fixed it by following these steps:

1. Log in to you GitHub account and navigate to Settings > Developer
   Settings > Personal Access Tokens
2. Click "Generate new token"
3. Add your message for this token: It's for Android Studio and you can
   use it also for new commits.
4. Then check the following boxes: repo, read:org, and gist
5. Click "Generate token"
6. Copy the generated token and return to Android Studio.
7. Log In With Token From Android Studio
8. In Android Studio, Navigate to File > Settings > Version Control >
   GitHub
9. Select the '+' and then choose "Log In with token".
10. Paste the copied token and click "Add Account".

Congratulations, you can now use your GitHub safely